# How to get the specific fields by API Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, jpa

I need to REST the request by the GET to transfer to the parameters of the field that I want to get from the database sql (from hibernate)

```
@GetMapping("/product")
public Object getProducts(@RequestParam(name = "fields") String fields) {
   // how?
}



@Repository
public interface ProductRuRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
@Query("SELECT ?1 FROM Product p")
List<Product> findByFields(String fields);
}
```

I'm waiting to get the fields that I passed to the parameter.
But the project does not compile

Comment: If you provided full code, then it doesn't compile because of your `getProducts()` should return an object, but it does nothing at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code to this structure:

Associate product repository to your rest controller.

```
   @RestController
   class ProductController {

    ProductRuRepository productRepository;

    @GetMapping("/product")
    public List<Product> getProducts(@RequestParam(name = "fields") String fields) 
    {
    List<Product> productList = productRepository.findByFields(fields);
    return productList;  
    }

    }
```

Your repository will trigger runtime exception because of syntax issue in
JPA Query.

Change the query as mentioned below.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT :fields FROM Product as p")
List<Product> findByFields(String fields);
```

Comment: Sorry but not compile, error: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.designer.vorobeip.repository.ProductRuRepository.findByFields(java.lang.String)!

Comment: I think the issue is Hql query only..!